# Non-deterministic behavior in deciding whether it is a file or not?

Tags: c++, c, regex, file

I write a function to decide whether it is a file or not, see the code below:

```
bool isfile(const std::string & f) {
  struct stat st;
  stat(f.c_str(), & st);
  if(S_ISREG(st.st_mode)) {
    return true;
  } 
  return false;
}
```

But when I invoke the function with:

```
std::cout << isfile("/home/xxx/a*") << std::endl;
```

In `/home/xxx/`, there are some a0, a1... and other files.

The strange problem is that it will print `0` mostly but sometimes print `1`, I wonder that's the problem with the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't check the return value of `stat` and instead look at `st.st_mode` whether or not it contains valid data. So when `stat` fails, say because the file doesn't exist, you process nonsense data.

Comment: hi, can the parameter `pathname` in `stat` support `/home/a*` format?

Comment: Sure, that would check for a file called `/home/a*`.

Answer (score 0):

Note, the standard is for UNIX system calls and C library calls to return 0 on success, and a negative number on failure. As David Schwartz points out, your code ignores that.

I suggest:

```
bool isfile(const std::string & f) {
   struct stat st;
   if(stat(f.c_str(), & st) == 0 && S_ISREG(st.st_mode))
      return true;
   return false;
}
```

Comment: this code can't handle the case if file system failed in a short time

Comment: because in this case it will return false, but it is a regular file

Comment: Red herring argument. A file system failure will effect something, period. It may be the next call that tries to access the file. There are no guarantees when it comes to disks.

Comment: Besides, you should discuss that with the OP, not me. I was answering his question and showing how to check the return code correctly.